# Drawing Lines and Tags - limited datapoints

Tags: pine-script

Consider this simple Pine Script

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)
line.new(x1=bar_index[1], y1=low[1], x2=bar_index, y2=high)
label.new(bar_index, high)
```

[image]

It seems that the number of bars taken into consideration is about 50.
Is there a way to make this work for all the bars?

Answer (score 0):

Not with drawings, i.e., lines and labels, as they become victims of the [garbage collection explained in the usrman](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html#total-number-of-drawings).

You can plot objects on all the dataset's bars using the conventional Pine plotting functions such as `plot()` and `plotshape()`, but functionality is not equivalent.